# heloo all of talented friends my vs code is not opening

Tags: expression-encoder-sdk

hello all of talented friends  my vs code I not opening , I reinstalled it but still it is not opening , I completely uninstalled it and then reinstall but still it is not opening please help

Comment: Can you provide some logs, or anything else that could indicate the cause of failure. We can't help if we know nothing about the technical details about your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.